# JQuery Add an event to all cells in a n-th column

Tags: jquery, events, html-table, onblur

I am trying to add an **onblur** to each cell with an input in the specific column of the html table after table is created?

```
  $('#tableid td:nth-child(4) input').blur(function() { 
        alert('123')
     });
```

However, nothing happens when cell looses focus.

Comment: Check you're targeting the right column; `:nth-child` is 1-based, not 0-based as with pretty much everything else in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used method found  here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40562247/3934049. Everything works as expected now.

```
  $(document).on("blur","#tableid td:nth-child(4) input", function() { 
    alert(123);
  });
```